# primefaces dynamic tab render

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, tabs

I have some tabs and rendered attiributes. My problem is how can i set this tab's rendered attiributes to false when i close the tab. I set with setRendered method but the problem is renderTab1 variable still holds True. What i want to do is; setting renderTab1 variable to "False". By the way i have many tabs like 20-25. If you have any better solution you can share.

my xhtml;

```
   <p:ajax event="tabClose" listener="#{myController.onTabClose}"/>

   <p:tab id="firstTab" closable="true" 
   rendered="#{myController.renderTab1}"/>
```

my tabclose method;

```
public void onTabClose(TabCloseEvent event) {
    event.getTab().setRendered(false);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was find a solution and i need to did this to solve my problem.

My solution not only did with rendered, i needed to use one variable to render tab, and one to send you to position that will be my tab inside of my tabView 
some like this.

in the tabView set parameters like this...

```
<p:tabView id="idTabView" widgetVar="tabView" dynamic="true" cache="false">
   in tab
   <p:tab rendered="#{mb.valiable == 1}"><!--the number 1 is an example-->
   </p:tab>
</p:tabView>
```

On commandButton where i suppose is on the first tab i put this:

```
<p:commandButton
actionListener="mb.activeTab()"
update="@form"
oncomplete="PF('tabView').select(1);" <!--this line send to tab that you are rendering with your flag in mb "variable" if you are render TAB in position three you need to put PF('tabView').select(2);-->
```

on my MAnagedBean method:

```
mb{
   private int valiable;

   public voi activeTab(){
            setValiable(1);
   }

   //setter y getters
}
```

i hope help you my solution.
regards

Answer (score 0):

The `rendered` property of a JSF component is resolved multiple times throughout the JSF lifecycle, so setting it manually on an event is unlikely to work by the time JSF actually begins rendering.  The `rendered` attribute however can take the following values:

1. A boolean property: Eg. `rendered="#{myController.booleanProperty}"`
2. A method that returns a boolean: Eg. `rendered="#{myController.doStuffAndReturnBoolean()}"`
3. An EL expression that resolves to a boolean value: Eg. `rendered="#{myController.intValue gt 3}"`

Comment: So how can i get this boolean property. like "Boolean b = event.getTab().getRendered();"

Comment: @TurgutDsfadfa This is sort of a chicken vs. egg thing... perhaps you can just explain what you are trying to accomplish because I am sure there is a better way than what you are trying to do.

Comment: I have 3 buttons with named "open tab1","open tab2" and "open tab3". when user clicks these buttons, they activates(renders) related tabs(say them tab1,tab2 and tab3). For example if user clicks "open tab1" button, tab1 will rendered and if then user clicks "open tab2" button, tab2 also will rendered(now we got tab1 and tab2). Problem is closing tabs. For example if I close these 2 tabs(tab1 and tab2) and click to "open tab3" button, tab1 and tab2 is also getting activated because variables which i binded to their  rendered properties still holds "True" value.